# drupal 7.31- sub menus are not appearing on site

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

I am using drupal 7.31.
In My drupal site main-menus are created and displayed successfully.
Also I have added Sub-menus.But they are not displayed on site.
I cant understand why sub-menus are not appear on site.

I have added main menu using following steps : 
`Structure -> Menus -> Add link.` Also set "Show as expanded" checkbox checked for parent menu, and
"Enabled" is checked for both parent and sub/children menu.

Please suggest me solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Nice menu" module for drop down menu. You can download this module from [Nice Menus - Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus)

Answer (score 0):

are the submenu items outputted in your html ?
if so, then it's just a css related issue

Nice menus is indeed a nice alternative to the core menu system as is superfish
https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish

Comment: Nope... Submenu items are not outputted in html. They can be seen only at Administration -> Structure -> Menus ->List links

Comment: what theme are you using ?

Comment: Previously I was using Bartik7.31 (which is defult). Now I am using Nexus Theme 7.x-1.3. Both not work.

Comment: Could you try to tick the 'expanded' checkbox for the children too ? (known bug in nexus https://www.drupal.org/node/2088155), also try another browser ... hard to debug when i don't have a url or admin access ....

Comment: also found this so try it out =>The main menu in Bartik only displays the first level. Since it's hardcoded in page.tpl.php there's nothing you can do about it.

Here's how to get the menu to work properly:

In your theme settings (admin/appearance/settings/barti) disable "Main menu"
Go to admin/structure/block and add the "Main Menu" block to the header region (or wherever you want it)